# Converting list of ints to strings and printing results

Tags: python, list

Having a hard time converting some list elements from int to str. I keep getting the following error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This is a method that is being passed a list of int elements from another method.

```
def converter(scores_avg):
array_length = len(scores_avg)
for x in range(array_length):
    if x > 89:
        scores_avg[str(x)] = "A"
    elif x > 79:
        scores_avg[str(x)] = "B"
    elif x > 69:
        scores_avg[str(x)] = "C"
    elif x > 59:
        scores_avg[str(x)] = "D"
    else:
        scores_avg[str(x)] = "F"
    print(scores_avg)
    print("Grade for Test " + x + ": " + scores_avg[x])
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code has indentation errors, and is merely a function that you never call.
It does not throw the error you cite.

Comment: That said, the error appears simple: you passed in a list, but you're trying to index it with a string, just as the error message tells you.  You *force* the index to be a string, using `str(x)`.  Please describe how you're expecting this to work.

Comment: Right, I am passing a simple list of ints to the method. I'm not really sure, that's just something that I tried as simply scores_avg[x] threw the same error. I apologize as I'm not very great at python, but I don't know what I'm doing to make this not work

Comment: def converter(scores_avg):
    for x in range(len(scores_avg)):
        if x > 89:
            scores_avg[x] = "A"
        elif x > 79:
            scores_avg[x] = "B"
        elif x > 69:
            scores_avg[x] = "C"
        elif x > 59:
            scores_avg[x] = "D"
        else:
            scores_avg[x] = "F"
        print("Grade for Test ", x, ": ", scores_avg[x])
    print(scores_avg)


mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

converter(mylist)

Comment: The list gets overwritten with all Fs in the for loop instead of converting each individual list element against the string assignments @prune

Comment: That is because you never compare anything. You are comparing the index of the list and not its values.

Comment: gotcha, but how do you actually pull the value from that index?

Comment: You pull the value by repeating your materials on working with lists.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: @Prune do you include a backhanded comment after every tidbit of vague information? I thought that stack overflow was literally a community of coders helping each other out with the problems they are running into

Comment: The comments are intended to get to to look up the things you're supposed to look up, rather than simply giving you that information.  The rationale is explained in the posting guidelines.  This is to discourage people from cluttering Stack Overflow with inappropriate questions.  Please refer to the guidelines to refine your understanding of the site's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
def converter(scores_avg):
for x in range(len(scores_avg)):
    if x > 89:
        scores_avg[x] = "A"
    elif x > 79:
        scores_avg[x] = "B"
    elif x > 69:
        scores_avg[x] = "C"
    elif x > 59:
        scores_avg[x] = "D"
    else:
        scores_avg[x] = "F"
    print(scores_avg)
    print("Grade for Test " + x + ": " + scores_avg[x])
```

Try this. :)

Comment: I'm getting a lot better results, but now I see this:

    print("Grade for Test " + x + ": " + scores_avg[x])
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: I just solved that by using commas instead of +, but for some reason this for loop is overwriting my list data with all "F"